# Sibling selector before possible solutions with CSS only

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors, siblings

I have need of previous sibling selector in css. I know that there is no such selector or it is in beta testing, this makes sense because of performance and traversing.

But I want to achieve this using other tricks, but not sure which is better considering performance.

Here is my HTML layout

```
   <div class="accordion-menu">
        <ul class="accordion-list cd-accordion-menu is-root">
            <li class="accordion-list-item has-children">
                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon ion-settings"></span>
                    Sub Group 1
                </a>
                <ul class="accordion-list is-opened">
                    <li class="accordion-list-item has-children">
                        <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                            <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                            Sub Group 1.1
                        </a>
                        <ul class="accordion-list">
                            <li class="accordion-list-item">
                                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                                    Item 1
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="accordion-list-item">
                                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                                    Item 2
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="accordion-list-item">
                                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                                    Item 3
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="accordion-list-item">
                        <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                            <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                            Item 1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="accordion-list-item">
                        <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                            <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                            Item 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordion-list-item">
                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                    Sub Group 2
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="accordion-list-item">
                <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
                    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-bars"></span>
                    Sub Group 3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul> <!-- cd-accordion-menu -->
    </div>
```

Here most important part of CSS

```
  .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__link::before {
    margin-right: 4px;
    content: '\f125';
    font-family: "Ionicons"; }
```

If list item has children than link inside this item should have icon (chevron right) before it.

But I have another state `is-opened` of `accordion-list`. And when `accordion-list` with class `is-opened` link before icon should be changed to another content `content: '\f123';` (chevron down)

How can I achieve such behavior using only css, considering performance.
I know tricks like using checkbox, but maybe there are other ways to achieve this ?

I would be grateful for any help.

**UPDATE**

To make things more clear. This is part of HTML code where I need to select siblings.

```
  <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="#0">
  <span class="accordion-list-item__icon ion-settings"></span>
                    Sub Group 1
  </a>
  <ul class="accordion-list is-opened">
```

If as in example ul has class `is-opened` than sibling link above (in dom tree) `accordion-list-item__link::before` should change the icon.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I have only one idea is to add `is-opened` class to link itself when list is opened using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it means that if .accordion-list-item has both class has-children and is-opened then this css will be applied

**EDIT:**

```
.accordion-list.is-opened > .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__link::before {
        content: '\f123';
        }
```

Comment: Please note `is-opened` is class for list not for item

Comment: You are selecting direct child of opened list, but I need to select sibling, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this and check. Write 2 separate styles for both cases

```
1. ul.accordion-list > .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__link::before 
{ 
    content: '\f125'; 
}

2. ul.accordion-list.is-opened > .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__link::before 
{ 
    content: '\f123'; 
}
```

Comment: In your example it will select items inside open list, but I need to select sibling